# Write an equivalent C expression for x % 8?

Tags: c

I am just back from an interview and this question is bugging me. I was asked to write an equivalent expression for `x % 8` and I couldn't get it. I know it's something to do with 8 being in powers of 2 but I just can't figure it out. This seems like a great programmer community so I'm hoping anyone here can answer this?

Comment: `x % 8` is a perfectly valid C expression.

Comment: @BlacklightShining in fact the OP was asked for an _equivalent_ expression.

Comment: “What's the equivalent to `expression X` in `language L`?” to me suggests that X is not valid in L.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`x&7` is the answer. (I'm not some hot shot I just googled it)

Comment: Did that google page also mention what happens when the dividend is *negative* ? C99 keeps the dividend sign, so `(-11 % 8) = -3`, while `(-11 & 7) = 5`.

Comment: @WhozCraig And you might want to add that it's _implementation defined_ for C++ ISO 1998.

Comment: @devnull no kidding. that seemingly simple resolution has been tossed about on more standards between C and C++. through the years.

Comment: @WhozCraig Yes, [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) does give some insight into it.

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't google it. Although x&7 returns mathematically correct result as x%8 would return the closest negative modulus if x is negative. (http://codepad.org/XVxQ2XCH). Good point, though.

Comment: -1. This is apparently not _equivalent_, given that it behaves differently for negative numbers.

Comment: @darshandzend I only brought it up because its an *awesome* clarification to ask during the interview when being proctored on this question. Its a risk (bombing the questioner with clarification as to which standard we'll be using when formulating our answer), but in most cases, the interviewer never gave it much thought in the first place. =P

Comment: It's really not a bomber interview question but rather an indicator of senior dev knowledge based answer